# Did China censor Obama's inauguration in 2013?

Tags: united-states, international-relations, china, inauguration

Apparently China censored the 2017 Presidential inauguration of the United States, forbidding media outlets from streaming the event or publishing photographs of it. Only reprints of state-written reports are allowed.

Did China censor the 2013 inauguration as well, or only this one?

Answer (score 7):

### 2017

China did [censor this year's inauguration](https://www.ft.com/content/204e38a0-ded3-11e6-9d7c-be108f1c1dce), in a directive to media outlets. This's not surprising due to Trump's rhetoric towards China.

> It is forbidden for websites to carry out live streaming or picture reports of the inauguration.

---

### 2013

There isn't any definite article that states if China broadcasted that year's inauguration. However, I did find [an article published by state media CCTV](http://english.cntv.cn/program/newsupdate/20130121/100080.shtml).

---

### 2009

Obama's first inaugural speech was not planned to be censored initially, until he mentioned "communism".

In [an article by The Washington Times](http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2009/jan/21/obamas-inaugural-address-censored-china/), it states:

> Chinese who stayed up into the early hours to watch the historic swearing-in ceremony, looked on as the state-run China Central Television (CCTV) abruptly cut away from its coverage of Mr. Obama’s address when he spoke of how “earlier generations faced down fascism and communism.”
>
> The censors didn’t wait to hear the rest of the offending sentence — “not just with missiles and tanks, but with sturdy alliances and enduring convictions” and proceeded to mute the Chinese interpreter, abandon the shot of the U.S. Capitol and seek refuge with a flustered studio anchor.

---

In conclusion, it's unclear if the 2013 inauguration was censored. However, this year's is definitely not the first that is censored.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [LA Times](http://articles.latimes.com/2009/jan/22/world/fg-china-censor22), Yes, the Chinese did censor at least Obama's first inauguration. I don't know if they censored his second, but it seems likely.

Answer (score 1):

depending on your definition of "forbidding", "media" and "streaming". I know for a fact that 1) the state media did not broadcast Obama's 2nd inauguration and I would be surprised if they did the trump inauguration; 2) the state media reported Obama's 2nd inauguration and trump's inauguration; and 3) live broadcasting of obama's 2nd inauguration was available in China both via traditional media and via the internet.

so the answer can be "yes" and "no" depending on how you interpret those terms.